# Proving n is not divisble by m using Division Algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, divisibility, integers

When $n$ and $m$ are integers, how could I write a statement equivalent to the statement "$n$ is not divisible by $m$" using ideas from the Division Algorithm?

Comment: $$\exists q\in\mathbb Z,\exists r\in]0,m[\cap\mathbb N: n=mk+r$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you mean by this, but generally, '$n$ is not divisible by $m$' means that there does not exist an integer $k$ so that $n=mk$.

Please post a comment if you were looking for something different. Thanks!

Comment: actually, that really helps me to formulate a set theory statement that is equivalent, thank you!